# iotune qemu/KVM total_iops total_bytes limits

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, iostat

I have created some qemu/KVM virtual machines on SSDs.

The host has ~6 SSDs. 1 is being used for the OS, and each of the other SSDs has **two** VM guests.

I'm using `iotune` to limit the capabilities of these drives:

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='writeback' io='threads'/>
  <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/sdd/pz/heavy/virtual-machine-1/os.img' aio=''/>
  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
  <iotune>
      <total_iops_sec>3000</total_iops_sec>
      <total_bytes_sec>125829120</total_bytes_sec> #120Mb
    </iotune>
</disk>
```

When I SSH to one of the VMs and run `fio`, these limits appear to work - I can't get beyond 120Mb throughput or 3000 IOPS regardless of what configuration I use on fio (`--iodepth`, `--bs` `--rwmixread`, etc).

However, under load, when I run `iostat -xm 2`, I'm occasionally seeing the `writes per second` or `tps` jump above these limits.

With 2 VMs per drive, and these limits enforced, I should see a maximum of 6000 IOPS or 240Mb reads/writes. On the following output you can see this isn't the case:

```
Device:            tps    MB_read/s    MB_wrtn/s    MB_read    MB_wrtn
sdd            6515.00         0.00        23.10          0         46


Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sdd               0.00     4.50    0.00 7742.50     0.00    58.38    15.44     1.47    0.21    0.00    0.21   0.08  63.10
```

This isn't a one-off either. I have 4 servers running identical virtual machine setups, and I'm seeing this happen fairly frequently across all of the SSDs and all of the servers:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sdb               0.00     0.00    0.00 9588.50     0.00    33.59     7.17     1.47    0.16    0.00    0.16   0.06  52.85
sdd               0.00     0.00    0.00 8528.00     0.00    66.15    15.89     1.36    0.16    0.00    0.16   0.07  59.30
```

Is this a failing of my configuration, the qemu/KVM implementation or iostat's interpretation of these disk's performance?